# Perl part-of-speech tagging: need tag set for Lingua::EN::Tagger

Tags: perl

So, I want to use Lingua::EN::Tagger, but I can't seem to find the domain of tags (aka the parts of speech: ie MD, NN, etc.

I found something similar to what I want here: http://engtagger.rubyforge.org/
but this is for ruby, not perl, and I'm not sure if the tags are going to be the exact same set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag set is available in the readme from Lingua0EN-Tagger-0.23 (http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ACOBURN/Lingua-EN-Tagger-0.23/README)

```
Lingua::EN::Tagger 

This module uses part-of-speech statistics from the Penn Treebank
to assign POS tags to English text. The tagger applies a bigram (two-word)
Hidden Markov Model to guess the appropriate POS tag for a word.  That means
that the tagger will try to assign a POS tag based on the known POS tags
for a given word and the POS tag assigned to its predecessor.

The tagger tends to assume unknown words are nouns, but this behavior is 
configurable.

The POS tagger can also be used to find maximal noun phrases in tagged text.  
You can also use this module to extract all nouns and/or noun phrases.



TAG SET

----------------------------------------------------------------
The set of POS tags used here is a modified version of the
Penn Treebank tagset. Tags with non-letter characters have been 
redefined to work better in our data structures. Also, the 
``Determiner'' tag (DET) has been changed from `DT', in order to
avoid confusion with the HTML tag, <DT>. 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
CC      Conjunction, coordinating               and, or
CD      Adjective, cardinal number              3, fifteen
DET     Determiner                              this, each, some
EX      Pronoun, existential there              there
FW      Foreign words           
IN      Preposition / Conjunction               for, of, although, that
JJ      Adjective                               happy, bad
JJR     Adjective, comparative                  happier, worse
JJS     Adjective, superlative                  happiest, worst
LS      Symbol, list item                       A, A.
MD      Verb, modal                             can, could, 'll
NN      Noun                                    aircraft, data
NNP     Noun, proper                            London, Michael
NNPS    Noun, proper, plural                    Australians, Methodists
NNS     Noun, plural                            women, books
PDT     Determiner, prequalifier                quite, all, half
POS     Possessive                              's, '
PRP     Determiner, possessive second           mine, yours
PRPS    Determiner, possessive                  their, your
RB      Adverb                                  often, not, very, here
RBR     Adverb, comparative                     faster
RBS     Adverb, superlative                     fastest
RP      Adverb, particle                        up, off, out
SYM     Symbol                                  *
TO      Preposition                             to
UH      Interjection                            oh, yes, mmm
VB      Verb, infinitive                        take, live
VBD     Verb, past tense                        took, lived
VBG     Verb, gerund                            taking, living
VBN     Verb, past/passive participle           taken, lived
VBP     Verb, base present form                 take, live
VBZ     Verb, present 3SG -s form               takes, lives
WDT     Determiner, question                    which, whatever
WP      Pronoun, question                       who, whoever
WPS     Determiner, possessive & question       whose
WRB     Adverb, question                        when, how, however

PP      Punctuation, sentence ender             ., !, ?
PPC     Punctuation, comma                      ,
PPD     Punctuation, dollar sign                $
PPL     Punctuation, quotation mark left        ``
PPR     Punctuation, quotation mark right       ''
PPS     Punctuation, colon, semicolon, elipsis  :, ..., -
LRB     Punctuation, left bracket               (, {, [
RRB     Punctuation, right bracket              ), }, ]
```